# Append 2 querysets in Python without loosing their order

Tags: python, set

I have two separate query sets A and B, I want to append B to A without any constraint.

Let's assume two queryset A and B.

```
A = (1, 5, 7, 15, 20 )
B = (4, 6, 10,14, 19, 21)
```

Now What I really want:

```
Final_queryset = (1, 5, 7, 15, 20 ,4, 6, 10,14, 19, 21)
```

I just want to append B to A without giving any order_by and without disturbing any order.

Here I can not put any order_by constraint because it will disturb the order. I do not want to use list because list because it loads whole objects into memory and I have 50000- 60000 objects so I can not use list.

Any idea on how I can achieve this using only querysets in python

Answer (score 1):

You want [`itertools.chain(A, B)`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Comment: I tried  intertools but with intertools I can't used pagination. As my set length is in thousands I need pagination on them.

Comment: I have tried to using these methods:
1. intertools.chain
2. Directly writing SQL query.

I was getting desired set using intertools.chain but it seems like I can not apply pagination on the result. 

I thought of another alternative: I can probably write something that does what chain does, but presents an interface similar to queryset and is efficient. This is non trivial to write but I can at least try to make it work. I would look for alternative before, and if I wouldn't find any, that's probably what I would be doing.